# Existential conditional assignment operators in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, operators, conditional-operator

When reading the Coffeescript documentation, I was confused by the [scant documentation on existential operators](http://coffeescript.org/#operators). The documentation states

> It (`?=`) can also be used for safer conditional assignment than `||=`
>   provides, for cases where you may be handling numbers or strings.

What is the difference between the `?=` and `||=` operator and when should one be used versus the other?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`?` and `||` check entirely different (but overlapping) conditions.

The `||` operator works exactly the same way as it does in JavaScript so things like `0` and `''` are falsey as far as `||` is concerned; `||` checks truthiness in the JavaScript sense.

The `?` operator is converted to `== null` in the JavaScript so `a ? b` is only `b` when `a` is `null` or `undefined`; `?` checks definedness in the CoffeeScript sense.

Consider these:

```
for v in [false, 0, '', null, undefined, 6]
    do (v) ->
        a = v
        a ||= 'pancakes'
        console.log("#{v} ||= 'pancakes':", a)

for v in [false, 0, '', null, undefined, 6]
    do (v) ->
        a = v
        a ?= 'pancakes'
        console.log("#{v} ?= 'pancakes':", a)
```

The first loop will give you five pancakes and one `6`, the second loop will give you a `false`, `0`, `''`, two pancakes, and a `6`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PdLDe/1/

So if you only want JavaScript-style behavior (i.e. `0`, `false`, and `''` are to be ignored) then you probably want `||=`. If you only want to skip over `null` and `undefined` then you want `?=`.

Comment: I think you mean "#{v} .." not "#{a} ..", why print a twice?

Comment: @NickSotiros: I think you're right, the strings inside the `console.log` calls should (and now do) use `#{v}` while the second argument should be `a`. Thanks for the heads up.